# Rotate image or video captured from any UIImageOrientation to Portrait Oritentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I want record video or capture image from the iphone in any Orientation (Left, Down , Right, Up) and then show the video/image in Portrait mode. I am achieving this by the code

```
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage {
if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
[self drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.size}];
UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return normalizedImage; }
```

But the above code fails if the Portrait Orientation lock is On. When the lock is On i always get :

```
self.imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight
```

I want to perform the above action disregard of Orientation Lock.Looking for some help . Thanks

Comment: do u mean the screen orientation lock ?

Comment: Yes @Mr.T i meant the screen orientation lock